# Rails with Factory Girl Configuration possible Scoping Issue, best practices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

In the [Factory Girl getting started documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md) it says to include the helper module like this:

```
# RSpec
# spec/support/factory_girl.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

Inside the RSpec config block. But this doesn't work for me. I just put module inclusion the beginning of the `rails_helper.rb` and it works fine.

My question is why does the documentation say to put it in the config block? Should that be working? Am I going to run into method collisions. Am I going against best practices?

Answer (score 1):

Files residing in spec/support are not loaded by default. Uncomment line #21 in spec/rails_helper.rb for Rails 4.2.